# Jenkins - Terraform / Can’t find terraform jenkins section in System Configuration

Tags: jenkins

I installed [Terraform plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Terraform+Plugin) and its in the installed plugin. When I create new Item, I can see the terraform section in the `job configuration` - but the terraform installation is blank.

As I understand, I should install terraform binary by selecting the version in the `system configuration`. But there is no terraform section.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration and there should be a Terraform section